# Cargar JavScript en Django 3x

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-4

Tengo un problema con una plantilla Boostrap.

Cargué la carpeta static en la carpeta raiz del proyecto, la misma donde esta el manage.py

Cuando cargo la página desde el navegador tengo estos mensajes en amarillo en la consola del servidor:

```
[07/May/2020 03:53:32] "GET /static/jimg/undraw_posting_photo.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 1713
[07/May/2020 03:53:32] "GET /static/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1701
[07/May/2020 03:53:32] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1755
[07/May/2020 03:53:32] "GET /static/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1749
[07/May/2020 03:53:32] "GET /static/js/sb-admin-2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1686
[07/May/2020 03:53:32] "GET /static/index/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1728
[07/May/2020 03:53:32] "GET /static/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[07/May/2020 03:53:32] "GET /static/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1701
```

ES como si consiguiera los archivos, pero no los carga

Este el el código de las plantillas como cargo los scripts

```
{% load static %}

  <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="{% static 'js/sb-admin-2.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Page level plugins -->
  <script src="{% static 'index/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
  <script src="{% static 'js/demo/chart-area-demo.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js' %}"></script>
```

Y así tengo el archivo settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Si coloco la ruta completa en el archivo settings asi:

```
STATIC_URL = '/home/daniel/instancias/desarrollo/proyectos/maquetar/static'
```

Obtengo el mismo error

Que estoy haciendo mal??

Comment: Adjunta todo el código de la configuración de los archivos estáticos, por otra parte los archivos estáticos los guardas en el proyecto (`project/static/`) o en una carpeta `static` de una app (`project/app/static/`)?

Comment: Están en project/static, y la configuracion de los archivos estaticos es esa, las tengo en STATIC_URL = '/static/', en el archivvo settings.py

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal configurado los archivos estáticos, Django siempre busca los archivos estáticos en la carpeta `static` de cada aplicación, y en las rutas que indiques en [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs), según tus comentarios los archivos estáticos los guardas en la carpeta `static`, **pero en el proyecto**, Django no busca los archivos estaticos en esa carperta, por eso el error.

Tienes que indicarle a Django que busque en dicha carpeta de la siguiente manera (en el archivo `settings.py`):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

> [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) es la lista de carpetas donde Django buscará
>   archivos estáticos adicionales además de la carpeta `static` de cada
>   aplicación instalada.

---

Por otra parte, en tu pregunta haces lo siguiente que esta mal:

```
STATIC_URL = '/home/daniel/instancias/desarrollo/proyectos/maquetar/static'
```

> [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#static-url) **es para indicar la URL**, para usar cuando se hace
>   referencia a archivos estáticos.

Entonces esa cadena es una ruta, no una URL, lo cual esta mal. Debes tener claro que es [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#static-url).

Comment: Listo Amigo ese era el error. gracias!!